# Trying to load a webpack generated file in other app is not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack-4

I created a simple vue project using `vue create .` and default settings for vue2.

```
//vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        entry: {
            mvcapp: [
                './src/main-mvc.ts',
            ],
        },
    },
};
```

I have a simple code

```
// main-mvc.js
console.log('hello from mvc');
```

Now when running `yarn serve` its loading the app and showing the message in console. Till thats its fine.

Now I have another app (simple-app), in which there is sample.html file containing code

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/js/mvcapp.js"></script>
```

While the vue project running, I also started the simple-app using the live-server. Loading the sample.html in browser is loading the main.mvc.js file without any error, but there is no console message.

Can someone point me whats wrong here? Why the main-mvc.js file is not running the code correctly if linked in some other app?

Here is the full code of the generated js: https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#txgbtna5tas75m4ctl3jud

Comment: I'm not a vue developer but I don't believe you can just load a vue component by including the HTML and JS. You'd also need the framework, etc. If you want to use components like this you should look into web components.

Comment: First question, why are you trying to load a vuejs app inside a html document?

Comment: mvcapp.js is a simple js code it has nothing to do with vue. I m just passing it through the webpack